# What is the differences between the Intent constructions

Tags: android, android-intent

I wanted to know what is the differences between those implementetions:

First:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
intent = new Intent("myservice.MyReceiver");
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Second:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Both of them working and doing the same thing. I don't understand how to first method know what is the refer contex and I don't need to specific the contex like in the second method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Intent("myservice.MyReceiver")` is an implicit `Intent`. It does not define a specific receiver to talk to. Any receiver that is eligible and is registered to listen for an `Intent` with that action string will respond. Generally, this approach is avoided for security reasons. Also, implicit broadcasts cannot be received by receivers registered in the manifest on Android 8.0+.

`new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class)` is an explicit `Intent`. It identifies the specific app (via the `Context`, to get the application ID) and class (via the Java `.class` object) that is the receiver that should respond to the broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

If you just pressed ctrl + B (go to declaration) or ctrl+Q (see documentation) on both constructor, You will get answer.

```
/**
 * Create an intent with a given action.  All other fields (data, type,
 * class) are null.  Note that the action <em>must</em> be in a
 * namespace because Intents are used globally in the system -- for
 * example the system VIEW action is android.intent.action.VIEW; an
 * application's custom action would be something like
 * com.google.app.myapp.CUSTOM_ACTION.
 *
 * @param action The Intent action, such as ACTION_VIEW.
 */
public Intent(String action) {
    setAction(action);
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Create an intent for a specific component.  All other fields (action, data,
 * type, class) are null, though they can be modified later with explicit
 * calls.  This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is
 * intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the
 * system to find an appropriate class for you; see {@link #setComponent}
 * for more information on the repercussions of this.
 *
 * @param packageContext A Context of the application package implementing
 * this class.
 * @param cls The component class that is to be used for the intent.
 *
 * @see #setClass
 * @see #setComponent
 * @see #Intent(String, android.net.Uri , Context, Class)
 */
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```